# When and Why is is_singular('my_cpt') true while in_the_loop() is false?

Tags: loop, page-template

I'm using example code for a templating system.

Page at this address: `http://project.test/my_cpt/hello-post/`.

Cannot understand why `is_singular( 'my_cpt' )` is `true` while `in_the_loop()` is `false`.

Within the page template, it seems like [The Loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) "works":

```
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post();
        ?>
        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
        <?php
    } 
}
```

I guess my question is *when* are `is_singular() && in_the_loop()` both true?

And when I run `if ( have_posts() ) { while ( have_posts()...` is that *in* the loop or is it *creating* the loop?

### Update

Partly it has to do with which filter is being hooked in the function/method which performs the `if &&` test.

The example above is being used with the `template_include` hook, which is getting run for pages, posts and maybe even links, menus, media, etc. So that would be why both tests are necessary.

The filter looks like:

`add_filter( 'template_include', array( __CLASS__, 'my_template_include_method' ) );`

or if it was not calling a class method would just be:

`add_filter( 'template_include', 'my_template_include_function'  );`

The full method/function looks like:

```
public static function my_template_include_function( $original_template ) {
    if ( is_singular( 'my_cpt' ) && in_the_loop() ) {
        return wpbp_get_template_part( MMC_TEXTDOMAIN, 'content', 'my_template', false );
    }

    return $original_template;
}
```

The `wpbp_get_template_part` is from a plugin boilerplate I recently discovered called [Wordpress Plugin Boiler Plate](https://github.com/WPBP).

Since I'm looking, at the moment, a singular post, I can hook into `single_template` like this:

`add_filter( 'single_template', array( __CLASS__, 'my_single_include_function' ) );`

It looks like this:

```
public static function my_single_include_function( $single_template ) {
    global $post;

    if ( 'my_cpt' === $post->post_type ) {
            return wpbp_get_template_part( MMC_TEXTDOMAIN, 'single', 'my_template', false );
    }

    return $single_template;
}
```

The templates themselves look like: `templates/content-my_template` and `templates/single-my_template`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I guess my question is *when* are `is_singular() && in_the_loop()` both true?

Note that both `is_singular()` and `in_the_loop()` point to the main WordPress query [set via `wp()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp/) (see [Query Overview on WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Query_Overview)) which uses the global `$wp_query` variable.

Secondly, we create/start a loop when we call `have_posts()` and `the_post()`, and only after that would `in_the_loop()` return a `true`. Example:

```php
// For the main query.
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        var_dump( in_the_loop() ); // true
        ...
    endwhile;
}
```

Therefore the `is_singular() && in_the_loop()` would only return `true` when:

1. You're on a singular WordPress page like `example.com/sample-page/` (a single Page; post type `page`) and a CPT page like in your case (`example.com/my_cpt/hello-post/`) where the post type is `my_cpt`.
2. And that you're in the loop for the main query.

So for example with your `my_template_include_function()` function, using the `is_singular( 'my_cpt' )` would be sufficient and I don't see why should you check for `in_the_loop()` there — single templates should display/start the loop for the main query, so by the time WordPress runs the `template_include` or `single_template` hook, that loop has **not** yet started or that you're not yet in the main query's loop.

Do correct me if I'm wrong/mistaken, though. :)

**(Update)** If your function (e.g. the `my_template_include_function()`) is actually being hooked to another hook which indeed runs in the main query's loop, then yes, you can use `in_the_loop()` there. Example:

1. The filter: ( if in a (child) theme, this would be placed in the `functions.php` file )

   ```php
   function my_custom_single_template_part( $template ) {
       if ( is_singular( 'my_cpt' ) && in_the_loop() ) {
           return '/path/to/your/template-part.php';
       }

       return $template;
   }
   add_filter( 'my_single_template_part', 'my_custom_single_template_part' );
   ```
2. The main loop:

   ```php
   if ( have_posts() ) {
       while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
           $template = apply_filters( 'my_single_template_part', 'template-parts/content' );
           get_template_part( $template );
       endwhile;
   }
   ```